# Change Bootstrap NavBar Image on Scroll when Awake

Tags: scroll, navbar

I'm stuck, I cannot figure out how to change the image source (white logo to a black logo) during scroll. 
Here is a link to the page I'm working on:
https://www.camarilloflightinstruction.com/sandbox/2020/index.html

If you scroll the page you'll notice that the logo changes the font format from WHITE FRONT W/ DARK BACKGROUND to BLACK FONT W/ White Background

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a jquery `.scroll()` event to test the `scrollTop()` value of the window (checking whether page is scrolled near the top or not), then change the `src` attribute of the image depending on that value. The value of the window's `.scrollTop()` will increase as you scroll down.

Try adding this to the very end of your `<body>` element, after your other `<script>` elements:

```
<script>

  var base = 'https://www.camarilloflightinstruction.com/sandbox/2020/images/';

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
      $('nav.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src', base + 'CFI_black.png')
    }
    else {
      $('nav.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src', base + 'CFI_white.png')
    }
  })

</script>
```